# How to increase a simple counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my  home.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <div class="bloc-article">
            <div class="article">
                <%= image_tag(article.picture, alt: "Article", width:"230", height:"240")%>
                <div class="align-content-column">  
                    <div class="celsuis"><span class="moins">- </span> <%= article.counter %>°  <span class="plus">+</span></div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <%= article.title %>
                    </div>
                        <h2><%= article.price %> €</h2>
                    <div class="desc-author">
                        <p><%= article.description[0, 200] %>....</p>
                        <div class="author-deal">
                            <h3><%= article.author %></h3>
                            <div class="alert alert-info"><%= link_to "Voir le Deal", article_path(article) %></div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>        
        <% end %>

</div>
```

I have a `span` `-` and a `span` `+`. I want put an `onClick` method to increase for `+` and decrease for `-`.

To do  that I have a database with `article.counter` (auto-generate number with `Faker::numb`)
With Vue.js I can do that easily, but on Ruby on Rails I am totaly lost.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking but the variable `@variable = 4` only lives for as long as rails is processing the request. As soon as the the response is sent its gone. If you want to to persist a counter between requests you have to store the value somewhere persistent like the database, the session, memcached/redis, the file system etc. This applies to applies to most server side programming in general.

Comment: Yes i have edit, I hope is mor clear.

Comment: Do you want to increase/decrease the number on the client only? Or is the intention that this change is will be notified to the server and updated in the database? You say it's easily done by Vue.js, but Vue.js doesn't save the change to the database and only updates what the client displays.

Comment: Yes i want update on my database and on resfreshing update for client vue.

Vue js i do easily that with methods put and get. And is update in real time.
But ROR i don't know who do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a Model "Article" with a column "quantity". You could do something in the lines of this (I haven't tested it, just giving you a guideline)

As long as you use the normal resources in your routes:

In your view:

```
<%= form_for (@article), method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.button "-", name: "update", value: "decrement" %>
  <%= f.button "+", name: "update", value: "increment" %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(whatever you use to find it)

  if params[:update]["increment"]
    @article.quantity += 1
  elsif params[:update]["decrement"]
    @article.quantity -= 1
  end

# repond_to here and so on
# and don't forget to @article.save

end
```

You could then use jQuery (probably no need for an onClick event) to render the part where you show the count in the view.

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of serious issues about understanding Rails applications (and web applications in general). Here are some hints:

1. All Ruby code (including those snippets inside `<% %>`) is evaluated on the server.
2. All JavaScript code in a Rails application is evaluated on the browsers.
3. The server and the browsers are different computers, so they don't share memory and thus objects.
4. A browser can't call Ruby methods as the Ruby code can only be evaluated on the server. A browser can only *ask* the server to do something via sending HTTP requests.
5. When a request is finished and the web page is shown on the browser, the server knows the browser no more, and every bit of memory on the server that's associated with the request becomes garbage.

Comment: Yes i understand is not the same memory, thanks you.
I edit my post with my actual problem